# editing file not taking default value=image_name

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, dropify

**View**

```
<form class="m-form" action="<?php echo AURL;?>products/update_product/<?php echo $products['product_id'];?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="file" name="product_image_name" class="form-control m-input dropify" placeholder="" data-default-file="<?php echo Website_Assets.'images/'.$products['product_image_name'];?>" value="<?php $products['product_image_name'];?>" data-max-file-size="2M" required>

</form>
```

In above code product_image_name not taking any value but showing the image picking the path and when I change image it post the image_name

**Controller**

```
public function update_product($product_id)
    {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r ($_FILES['product_image_name']);
        echo "</pre>";
        exit();
    }
```

changing the image works ok but if i donot change image its not picking the default value of the image

Comment: input `type="file"` dont work like normal fields.

Comment: You can't set a default value/filename for file inputs

Comment: @kerbholz how can i pass the default values of image name as like hidden or something? i thought there can be something like value="" in input tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

**Short answer:** An `input` of type `file` can not have a default value.

Instead use an `<img />`-tag to show default images. For example:

```
<img src=" <?php echo Website_Assets.'images/'.$products['product_image_name'];?>" />
```

---

**Normal answer:** Assuming you are trying to upload an image, save it to the entity that is behind the form and later edit it; try to think around using just the one field. Instead perhaps a sequence like this:

1. Upload a file using the upload field
2. Save the uploaded file on the machine that runs PHP (server-side)
3. Store the path to the uploaded file in the entity
4. In the edit view of the entity show both:

   - the image that was uploaded (or a placeholder)
   - an upload field to upload a new image

Good luck!

**Tip:** You might also want to have a look at open source libraries like [dropzonejs](http://www.dropzonejs.com/). Existing libraries often give examples and excellent documentation. This example visually combines the upload field with the display field.

Comment: Thanks @Webber
i used 1 input type hidden to pass the name of default image and
2 inputs type:
 first is disablde but showing default image and second is for uploading file

Comment: @Loek `<img src=" <?php echo Website_Assets.'images/'.$products['product_image_name'];?>">` thats also good but i want the same layout as the input field of the image i am using dropify class

Comment: @AmirKhan I just improved a suggested edit that edited that line in, sorry if it's incorrect!